# Read 4d .vol cine file from GE ultrasound

Tags: c++, render, vtk, volume, 4d

How do you view a 4d cine file(.vol kretz file format from GE).Can it be done using any libraries like VTK?

Right now I have tried exporting the file to .vtk format using 3dSlicer and rendered it as a 3d volume. Are there any other ways to load the file in the .vol format instead of converting it?

Comment: Related: [Loading of GE/Kretz ultrasound volumes (.vol file)](https://discourse.slicer.org/t/loading-of-ge-kretz-ultrasound-volumes-vol-file/808/125?page=7)